# How to send extra fields with an entity object in request body spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating a spring boot app where I have a post route which post the course details.

`Course.java`

```
public class course{
  String name;
  String days;
}
```

Now while sending a post request to post it,I have to add few extra fields like:

`sort_order`,`page_size`

My Post Mapping looks like this:

```
public course postcourse (@RequestBody course c)
{
}
```

In the above function the request body will be:

```
{
   "name":"Java",
   "duration":"12"
}
```

but I want my request to be:

```
{
     "name":"Java",
     "duration":"12",
     "page_size":10,
     "sort_order":"reverse"
}
```

I can't add `sort_order` and `page_size` in entity object as its not a good practice.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local class could help you to resolve this

```java
public course postcourse (@RequestBody course c) {
    class postCourse extends course {
        int page_size;
        String sort_order;
    }
    course yourCourse = new postCourse();
    …
    
    return yourCourse;
}
```

Hope this work.